# Pass IFrame HTML to Server

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, urlencode, url-encoding

I'm trying to figure out how can I pass HTML of an iframe to the server without it getting html encoded.

Right now I am using CKEditor to enter some text. Part of that I use a plugin to embed a video into that content. When that plugin runs, it generates following HTML:

```
<div class="videodetector">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eSYKJ8WQ508?autohide=1&controls=1&showinfo=0" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

However, when I retrieve that value with javascript or jquery, the url gets HTML encoded and looks like this:

```
<div class="videodetector">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eSYKJ8WQ508?autohide=1&amp;controls=1&amp;showinfo=0" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

The problem is that I am sending the entire content of ckeditor back to the server as HTML. And because this video is burred among other content as part of the same html. How do you handle a scenario like this? I've tried using various html decode methods, but none work. Example is `decodeURI`. The weird part that I am seeing in that encoded url is that only ampersands got encoded, how come?